# Why doesn't the Open File Dialog Window open?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007

I was recently upgraded from Windows XP to Windows 7 while my version of Office remained the same (Office 2007 pro) and I face an issue with commands/menus that try to open a popup window in the Office applications.

**Example 1**: I have a draft email in Outlook open. I click on "Attach File" but the popup window to attach the file never appears.

**Example 2**: I have Excel open. I click on the Ribbon Button (Office Button) then Open and the popup to select the file doesn't appear.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

***Update:*** I suspected that something may be wrong with how my graphics cards renders windows. So, I changed my theme from **Aero** to **Windows 7 Basic** and then to **Windows Classic**.

Interestingly, when using the **Windows Classic** theme, pop up windows work properly, but **Aero** and **Windows 7 Basic** don't allow the window to pop up.

Any ideas what can be causing that?

Comment: You explained the issue well, but there are a few things we need to know. Since being upgraded, have all the Windows Updates been installed and any Office updates? If you suspect the graphics card, have you verified you are using the proper drivers? Have you attempted a repair install?

Comment: This is difficult for me to say because I am in a corporate environment and I do not have admin rights on my PC (I am actually restricted in a lot of things). From what I see though Office 2007 with SP3 installed and Windows 7 Enterprise with Service Pack 1.

Comment: In that case, this is off topic per the [help]. You need to contact your IT department.

Comment: I did, and they were unable to help me. The IT person was advising me that my computer has been up and running for too long and hence this is the issue. However, I rebooted with her on the phone yesterday and the issue appeared again today, so this can't be the issue especially if this keeps happening.

Comment: Sorry, for your frustration with their inability to help you. Still this is off topic because *issues specific to corporate IT support* are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Your Open File dialog box may be opening but in a location outside your display.

To check for this situation, take the usual steps to open a file.  When you expect the dialog box to appear, press Alt+Space Bar, then press X.  This should maximize the window.  If your dialog box is open, then it should fill your entire screen.  If the dialog box does not appear then you ahve other problems.

If you have the maximized dialog box, then you have to work on moving it to a location you can see. In the maximized window, press Alt+Space Bar again then R.  This will restore the box to the original size.  Again press Alt+Space Bar then M. Press the right cursor key for a short time (4 to 6 seconds). If the hidden dialog box was to the left of your display, a frame will appear moving to the right. When you see this frame, press Enter. If nothing appears press Esc a few times to cancel the process. Repeat the entire process for all the directions.  If a maximized dialog box appears but you cannot see the frame moving in the 4 cardinal directions, then the box is at a diagonal to the main display.